# Create dynamic variables for lines using konva framework and FOR loop

Tags: javascript, konvajs

How can I create n lines with different names (like "Line_" + i) using a FOR LOOP and konvajs.?

I tried the statement:

```
var eval("Line_" + i) = new kanva.line()
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use arrays.....

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You can only create 'dynamic' variables as attributes of some object. You can use window, but you should avoid that as it creates global variables that will cause problems. Instead, create a parent object solely to act as the holder of the dynamic variables. See the snippet below.

For anywone drawn to this question by the mention of paralell lines in Konva js, please see an example in the [Konvas library docs here.](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Line_-_Simple_Line.html). The example draws parallel lines with bends, but you could easily follow and not include the extra points.

```js
var foo = {}; // create an object. You can use window for this if you are not worried about scope.

// use a loop to create some line objects.
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i = i + 1){

  foo['line_' + i] = {name: 'line ' + i};

}

// now you can refer to the line objects via the 'variable' name, link line_3
console.log('Object line_3.name=' + foo.line_3.name);

// and of course you can use the arry-like notation
console.log('Object line_7.name=' + foo['line_7'].name);

// and you can iterate them
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i = i + 1){
  console.log('Object line_' + i + '.name=' + foo['line_' + i].name);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I know do that and I did it like this:

Comment: var Line_0 = new Konva.Line({
      points: pointes_0,
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      lineCap: 'round',
      lineJoin: 'round'
    });
    var Line_1 = new Konva.Line({
      points: pointes_1,
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      lineCap: 'round',
      lineJoin: 'round'
    });
   and so on. I don't want to repeat a statement ten times and use, in stead, a FOR LOOP. I did it also but because I need names "Ligne_n" to manipulate then with events. My problem is in the dynamic creation of this name.